# PHPUnit Test Explorer with Xdebug - VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpunit, xdebug, test-explorer

I have recently installed Test Explorer UI for VSCode. I intend to use it with PHPUnit.

However, I do not see the debug symbol against my test. Also, the debugger points on my test file are never hit.

My launch.json is as below :

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9099,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/usr/share/nginx/": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9099,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/usr/share/nginx/": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- Test Explorer UI - v2.20.4
- PHPUnit Test Explorer - v2.0.76
- PHP Debug - v1.17.0

Can someone please help me understand if I am missing anything.
I am able to debug the regular code/php files, but not my tests.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Unfortunately, there is no elegant solution now.

My solution is setting `xdebug.start_on_request = yes` in php.ini.